# How to drop multi field partition by one field?

Tags: clickhouse

I have table like this:

```sql
create table if not exists aggregator.raw_data (
topic String,
integration_id String,
batch_id String,
kafka_ts DATETIME64(3),
insert_ts DATETIME64(3),
data Map(String, String)
) engine=MergeTree
order by (integration_id, kafka_ts)
partition by (integration_id, toStartOfHour(kafka_ts), batch_id);
```

and need to drop partition by batch_id, i try:

```
ALTER TABLE aggregator.raw_data DROP PARTITION '333-7c149299-f603-436a-a934-4dfbcebe4e68';
```

and:

```
ALTER TABLE aggregator.raw_data DROP PARTITION (batch_id = '333-7c149299-f603-436a-a934-4dfbcebe4e68');
```

Both approaches failed. Is it even possible to drop a composite partition on one field?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [How to Set Partition Expression](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/alter/partition#how-to-set-partition-expression) topic you may try to generate the corresponding commands with the following statement.

```
select DISTINCT 'ALTER TABLE "' || database || '"."' || table || '" DROP PARTITION ' || partition
from system.parts 
where database = 'aggregator' and table='raw_data' and active = 1
and extractAll (partition, '[^()'',]+')[3] = '333-7c149299-f603-436a-a934-4dfbcebe4e68'
```

`system.parts.partition` contains a string representation of tuple of constants for you partition key like `('integration_id x','YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS','batch_id y')`.
What the query does is generating the corresponding `ALTER TABLE ... DROP PARTITION` statement for the rows with 3-rd value (the `batch_id` column is 3-rd in the `PARTITION BY` expression) equal to your desired `batch_id`.

Comment: Thanks Mark! 

I also came to the conclusion in the end that I need to do through this system table. It seemed to me easier to get a list of suitable partitions for a separate request, and then insert values in the program code through a template.